# Selecting Database to Log onto from PHP Login Page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, I'm new to PHP and dumb as a brick, so please excuse me for asking for help on something that someone might have done before.

Scenario:

I have 10 Databases with exact same structure. I need to select the Database (by typing in it's name ex. company_a1 company_b2 etc.) at the Login Page. Then log into that selected Database and continue.

So far everything I found only show's static connections.

I'm looking into using PDO.

Anybody with any ideas would be appreciated.

So far I get this to work, but now how to keep this connection on all other pages?

I also thought of using a Database class, but have no idea how to implement it.

login.php

```
<form action="login-check.php" method="post">
    <label for="co_db">Company Key:</label>
    <input name="co_db" type="text" placeholder="Company Database" required>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" required>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" required>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Please keep in mind I'll clean Input later on, just need it to work first.

login-check.php

```
<?php

$db_name = $_POST['co_db'];

$host = 'localhost';
$db_file = $db_name; //Database Name from $_POST
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_file, $db_username, $db_password);

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
}
?>
```

I thought of using $_SESSIONS to store the $db_name, but not sure how to manage it.

I would like to create a Class like this and pass the $db_name to it, but have no clue how to do this?

```
<?php

class Database
{   
private $host = "localhost";
private $db_name = "dblogin";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
public $conn;

public function dbConnection()
{

    $this->conn = null;    
    try
    {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    return $this->conn;
}
}
```

Sorry if it's messy, but I hope someone can make sense of it all.

Regards

Chris

Comment: yeah session is a decent idea. `session_start();` at the top of every page (or in shared header file, if you have one). `$_SESSION["db"] = $db_name;` in your login page. Then `$db_name = $_SESSION["db"];` whenever you need to retrieve it.

Comment: Exactly When you call dbConnection function and pass dbname, it will return connection object that you need to store into the session. That is it, use the session stored connection in all page when ever required!

Answer (score 0):

If you run as first query:

`USE mydatabase;`

All next queries will use this database as default, you don't need to specify it in any query.

Comment: I think Chris is looking for the database name to persist between page views. `USE` would work, but only within a single page view - any new connections will go back to the default database (or no database selected).

Comment: It depends on how he organize the code, for example if you access to the website through a sub-domain, you can get the db using the third-level of the domain. Or you can store it in a session, and then execute the "use" query calling it as first query. But the way is always the same :P

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. I just wanted to clarify that the `USE` information does not stretch across connections.

Comment: Will definitely try the $_SESSIONS idea and get back to you guys after the weekend. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: So how do I pass the $_SESSION  variable to my Database Class?

    <?php


    private $db_name = $_SESSION['db_name']; //Throws an error

Comment: Without the error we can't help you, anyway check here for correct session usage: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db_name' (T_VARIABLE) in dbconfig.php with above code...